# Unsupported Media Type VIDEO error - Instagram API Publishing video

Tags: instagram-api

I want to share a .mp4 video with Instagram API using PHP. I use the following codes for sharing. Even though I entered the media_type parameter as REELS, I get this error. I wonder where the problem is?

```
$config = array( // instantiation config params
    'user_id' => $myInstagramBusinessAccId,
    'access_token' => $myFacebookAccessToken,
);

// instantiate user media
$media = new Media( $config );

$videoContainerParams = array(
    'caption' => $caption,
    'video_url' => $videoUrl,
    'thumb_offset' => 1000,
    'share_to_feed' => false,
    'media_type' => "REELS",
);

// create video container
$videoContainer = $media->create( $videoContainerParams );

echo '<pre>';
print_r($videoContainer);
return;
```

[error] => Array
(
[message] => Invalid parameter
[type] => OAuthException
[code] => 100
[error_subcode] => 2207067
[is_transient] =>
[error_user_title] => Desteklenmeyen medya türü VİDEO
[error_user_msg] => Media_type için VIDEO değeri kullanımdan kaldırıldı. Instagram akışında bir video yayınlamak için REELS medya türünü kullan. Bir video yayınlamak için lütfen https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/media#creating adresini ziyaret et.
[fbtrace_id] => A40AryGmv1WLJ_T3BwpWOKb
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you are using the github jstolpe/instagram-graph-api-php-sdk.

If that is the case then hard coded in their code is 'media_type' => 'VIDEO'

If you comment it out .. should work. I think you can find it in instgram/user/media.php   around line 86 or so, comment out this line:

$postParams['params'][Params::MEDIA_TYPE] = MediaTypes::VIDEO;

Rgds

Mike

Comment: Thank you very much Surreall. I did what you said and it worked. It never occurred to me to look at the file in the library. Thank you again

Comment: You are welcome! I only know cause i spent hours trying to fix it mysefl .. and i eventually gave up and followed the path through :-)